# getting search box and open editors in same explorer tab in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I am getting the search and open editor in same explorer tab and the search icon is missing on the left side in visual studio code can you please tell me how to get the search icon back on left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you dragged the `Search` header into the Explorer view.  Just drag `Search` from where it is onto the Side Bar.

[image: dragging the Search View]